# How to search for, or return, extended attributes in a here.com search?

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to search for businesses with disabled (wheelchair) access.  Google led me to https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics_api/media-type-place.html where the 'Media Types' documentation describes 'Extended Attributes', one of which is `disabledAccess`.  I cannot see this attribute in my search results, or see a way to query for businesses with this attribute either available, or set to a certain value.

My Javascript currently looks like:

```
request('https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/explore' +
        '?at=' + userLocation.lat + ',' + userLocation.lng +
        '&cat=restaurant' +
        '&app_id=' + appID +
        '&app_code=' + appCode)
```

This returns results but no mention of extended attributes is apparent.  The word 'extended' or 'disabled' is not present in the response.

I have tried the demo lat,lng from a google example `{lat: -33.866, lng: 151.196}` and also that of New York City `{lat: 40.71, lng: -74.006}`.  The docs do say that if no extended attributes are available for a business then the element is omitted completely from the results, but surely there would be something for one of the businesses at those locations.

I tried adding a `&cs=disabledAccess` to the query, but got an error that `disabledAccess` is not a valid category.

How do I get extended attributes in the results, or for bonus points, query based on extended attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only looking at two locations, it's very likely that the locations you queried had no 'Extended Attributes' at all.  I would try it at a few chain restaurants/areas in tech cities (SF/NY should be fine) but it's unfortunately likely there's nothing you can do here since the data is sparse.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ted. I have had to give up on here.com, since wheelmap.org is giving me useful data and has an API for updating data back to them, I've gone with using that.  If I get around to trying other locations and see extended attributes returned, I can probably mark your answer accepted.  As I said, I remain skeptical that a location in NYC did not have any places with any extended attributes, but maybe I picked a stupid lng,lat.